# Typescript intellisense: suggest common export names/types for files in a directory

Tags: typescript, express, implements

I don't think this is possible, but is there any way for intellisense to suggest certain properties to be exported from each typescript file in a directory, or matching a filename glob?

For example, I have a directory of route handlers. I'd like each file to handle one route. So my project structure is like:

```
/src
  /endpoints
    route1.endpoint.ts
    route2.endpoint.ts
  index.ts
```

And each `*.endpoint.ts` file will export some (and some optional) variables:

```
export const path = '/my-route-1';
export const method = 'post';
export function handler(req, res) {
  res.send('hello');
}
```

I'd like intellisense to to suggest  `path`, `handler`, and other exports in `*.endpoint.ts` files.

I know I can do this sort of with class implements, or maybe even typescript decorators. But curious if it can be done to export properties names/types.

Comment: IntelliSense is just the code completion and not a tool to enforce certain code rules/styles. As far I can tell though, you can only write a custom linter rule that enforces a particular set of exports in certain files. Why do you want to do this in the first place? It seems to me, you're trying to dynamically import endpoint files. Even though I personally dislike dynamic imports you might try to write a custom type for the dynamically imported modules.

Comment: Oops! Enforce was too strong of a word to use. Don’t need to enforce, but would like to suggest to the user exports they can use. Yes this is for dynamic imports.

Comment: "Exports they can use" - do you mean in the result? For `const endpoint = await import("route1.endpoint.ts");` Intellisense should already show you code completion and hints for the `endpoint` object.

Comment: My verbiage could have been clearer again. Instead of “exports they can use”, I mean “exports they can define”. I really don’t think this is possible.